# codeigniter route removing function_name in url

Tags: codeigniter

I got stack on this in Codeigniter route, What do I want is to remove the function_name in url to be able to have a short url.

Here is the example  want to have in my url

> http://mysite.com/controller_name/function_name/id

to this

> http://mysite.com/controller_name/id

Is there any other solution to have this if cannot be done in route? thanks!

Comment: The index method is called automatically with `http://mysite.com/controller_name/id` without changing route.php

Comment: @Alfonso but I got 404 error here with myfunction(id)

Comment: Sorry, I was probably sleeping when comment here. @JD Guzman's solution does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the above didn't work you could try:

```
$route['controller_name/(:num)'] = 'controller_name/lookup_function/$1';
```

Not much different from what was already suggested other than a hard coded controller name.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it by trying:

```
$route['([a-z]+)/(\d+)'] = "$1/method/$2";
```

That is if you don't need to change the name of your method.

Comment: @noviceRick You need to replace `method` with the name of your method.